# How to have a process queue in AIX like xargs with "--max-procs"?

Tags: aix, xargs, batch-jobs

Consider a simple processing queue like:

```
cat list.txt | xargs -n1 -P20 process.sh
```

(*-P or --max-procs)*

How to have something like that in AIX ?

Comment: As this is a vendor specific enhancement, did you try the vendor specific name  `gxargs`instead of `xargs`?

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds6/xargs.htm

Comment: As mentioned before: `xargs`does not support the options you are looking for, but `gxargs` does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could emulate the same thing by replacing your xargs by a ksh script. Eg:

```
#!/bin/ksh
nproc=0 max=20
trap 'let nproc--' sigchld
while read file
do    while [ $nproc -ge $max ]
      do sleep 1
      done
      process.sh "$file" &
      let nproc++
done
wait
```

The shell variable `nproc` counts the number of processes it has run in
the background. When a process ends the shell traps the SIGCLD signal to
decrement the variable. A sleep polling loop stops more than `max` processes being started.

Comment: Works like a charm, but I needed to change it to work like gnu xargs.